# Не блокировать экран на открытой странице сайта

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

Поделитесь идеей как оставить активный экран при открытой странице на сайте. Делаю проект в котором несколько пользователей находятся на одной странице и ждут информацию. Нужно чтобы телефоны не блокировали экран спустя время - оно зависит от настроек смартфонов.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock Оно?

Comment: @HTOHOT в доке написано что не поддерживает сафари или я ошибаюсь? И нужно чтобы по http тоже работал. Иногда работа в локальной сети

Comment: android:keepScreenOn="true"

Comment: @Style-7 это наверное в приложении. Там точно это проще. Но меня интересует Java Script , я имел ввиду удержать активный экран на сайте.

Comment: И кто вам позволит такое сделать? Чтобы любая страница смогла подвесить экран включенным.

Comment: @Style-7 при просмотре видео экран остаётся активным.